# Restrict Action Within An ID?

Tags: jquery

How do I make a script only work for a particular ID? I have multiple div's with the class names .item-post within various ID's. How do I restrict the script to working only within a particular id?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".next" ).click(function() {
        $(".item-post:first").insertAfter($(".item-post:last"));
        $(".item-post:first").css('display','none');
        $(".item-post:first").fadeIn()
    });
    $( ".prev" ).click(function() {
        $(".item-post:last").insertBefore($(".item-post:first"));
        $(".item-post:first").css('display','none');
        $(".item-post:first").fadeIn()
    });
</script>
```

This is what I tried:

```
$('#layout-education-1').is({
    $(".next").click(function() {
        $(".item-post:first").insertAfter($(".item-post:last"));
        $(".item-post:first").css('display','none');
        $(".item-post:first").fadeIn()
    });
    $(".prev").click(function() {
        $(".item-post:last").insertBefore($(".item-post:first"));
        $(".item-post:first").css('display','none');
        $(".item-post:first").fadeIn()
    });
});
```

EDIT: Updated with fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/m5s8ad68/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    $("#layout-education-1 .item-post:first").insertAfter($("#layout-education-1 .item-post:last"));
    $("#layout-education-1 .item-post:first").css('display', 'none');
    $("#layout-education-1 .item-post:first").fadeIn()
});
$(".prev").click(function () {
    $("#layout-education-1 .item-post:last").insertBefore($("#layout-education-1 .item-post:first"));
    $("#layout-education-1 .item-post:first").css('display', 'none');
    $("#layout-education-1 .item-post:first").fadeIn()
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but the script will then "insertBefore/insertAfter" elements in other ID's, because there are other parents with child elements with .item-post. This method breaks the script from working as intended.

Comment: have you tried `$("#layout-education-1 .item-post:last")`

Comment: Yes, I also already tried that. That stops the script from doing anything.

Comment: I'm not seeing the fiddle but it might be because I'm on an iPhone

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add link.

Comment: I edited my answer and it seems to be working on the fiddle, unless there is something that I'm not noticing

Comment: Is there not a way that requires less edits for my client? This method requires 8 edits for my client if they are using multiple scripts.

Comment: Not that I can think of, but it should be easy to edit with a find and replace built into most software